# Isolating the first 6 characters of a filename and then renaming the file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just need the first 6 numbers of the file name. Examples of file names are:
`124523-name-date.txt, 
151546-name-date.txt, 
687239-name-date.txt` 
The first 6 numbers are completely random. There are multiple files.

```
import os
os.chdir("E:\img-renamer")

i = 0
for file in os.listdir('e:'):
 file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)

 i += 1
 new_file_name = 'student_0{}.jpg'.format(i)

 os.rename(file, new_file_name)
```

Comment: Are there multiple files?

Comment: Please add what about your code does not work. Just copying code without describing it is not very helpful.

Comment: The first 6 characters of `file_name`? That is spelled `file_name[:6]`.

Comment: There are no errors, I just can't figure out how to isolate the first 6 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the glob module:

```
import os
from glob import glob

for file in glob("*.txt"):
    os.rename(file,file[:6]+'.txt')
```

Comment: I forgot the .txt extension, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, now is there a way that I can use that to rename the file?

Comment: I did forget to mention that the name is actually someone's name and there are a lot of them...

Comment: There are about 100 files using someone's actual name like 123456-AlexDiret-June7. But they all have different names.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help.